# xamarin forms - HttpClient post request postAsync not working

Tags: post, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I am try in to post data from HttpClient but it is not working.

i am getting error message as following:

{StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 30 Mar 2017 06:10:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Content-Length: 36
}}

my Code is as following:

```
public void RefreshDataAsync(Persons selectedData)
        {
                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var persons = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(selectedData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    var httpResponseMessage = client.PostAsync("http://169.254.80.80:62510/api/Person/SavePerson", persons).Result;
                    if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var responceString = httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
        }
```

getting data method is as following:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public int SavePerson([FromBody]string persons)
        {

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var aa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persons>(persons);
            int Success = 0;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SavePerson", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = aa.Name;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = aa.Age;
                    var parm1 = new SqlParameter("@Success", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500);
                    parm1.Size = 500;
                    parm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm1);
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    object retValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (cmd.Parameters["@Success"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                        Success = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Success"].Value);

                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    return Success;
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried to run with "**HttpRequester**" tool so it is working properly. i am getting response in json string. but it is not working when i am calling this method from emulator.

Comment: Internal Server error (500) is basically just that, something goes wrong at the server. If you say the request is going right from another tool, then probably the server error is caused by malformed data. So you have basically two options here: inspect your request from your app with a tool like Fiddler or inspect the server-side logs and see what is going wrong. Based on the information you are giving is it is hard to tell what is wrong, it is just guessing.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, i am posting request from emulator. and i think fiddler is not displaying request from emulator. because my request call not display in in it.

Comment: If you set it up right, it will display the request. Anyway, you could turn it around. Run your emulator against the server which is attached to a debugger and put breakpoints in your server to see what data is coming in and what is happening.